# After importing nltk nltk.download() is not working

Tags: python, nltk

This error messages comes up every time

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 655, in          download

    self._interactive_download()
    File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 974, in      _interactive_download
DownloaderGUI(self).mainloop()
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1234, in __init__
self._fill_table()
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1530, in _    fill_table
items = self._ds.collections()
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 499, in collections
self._update_index()
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 825, in _update_index
ElementTree.parse(compat.urlopen(self._url)).getroot())
File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1187, in parse
tree.parse(source, parser)
File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

And the downloader window opens without anything or list. I have checked downloader.py and it contains the right and new default link of the corpora.

I am using Windows standard edition.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Is it an option to try reinstall?

Comment: reinstalled but it didn't helped
nltk downloader is not working

Comment: Can you check if you python version matches with the requirements for nltk. It doesn't seem like a nltk issue.

Comment: yes it does match i am using nltk 3.0.4 and it supports python 2.6 and above

Comment: Not exactly: `NLTK requires Python versions 2.6-2.7 or 3.2+`. But you're still officially supported.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce. Installed Python3.4 (32-bit) freshly on my Windows 7 running in virtualbox. Then installed nltk via `pip install nltk` under admin prompt. No problems importing nltk nor downloading the data. Have you tried doing it without gui downloader via `python -m nltk.downloader -d C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data all`?

Comment: i have made a ubntu virtual machine and it's working fine there